# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"""'

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

#read in data and extract columns
cols = np.loadtxt('CST210.txt') 
Day1Attendence = cols[:,0]
Day2Attendence = cols[:,1]

#calculate the total attendence over the two days
TotalAttendence = Day1Attendence + Day2Attendence

#create second array from Day1Attendence and Day2Attendence
outArray = np.column_stack((Day1Attendence,Day2Attendence))

#save to test file
np.savetxt('Totalattandence.txt',outArray, delimiter =  'A')
```

This is the error code I'm getting

> runfile('/home/kasey/Documents/module1code.py',
>   wdir='/home/kasey/Documents') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/home/kasey/Documents/module1code.py', wdir='/home/kasey/Documents')
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/home/kasey/Documents/module1code.py", line 13, in 
>       cols = np.loadtxt('CST210.txt')
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   1101, in loadtxt
>       for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   1028, in read_data
>       items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   1028, in 
>       items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>
> File
>   "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   746, in floatconv
>       return float(x)
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"""'

Comment: show lus the contents of 'CST210.txt'

Comment: This is the contents of                                                                                                27 75
32 23
54 52
56 53
85 56
95 26
96 72
96 33
93 25
94 23
45 56
50 45 The numbers are in two columns the the first number goes next to the second number and so fourth

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code to make it more readable

Comment: what do you mean its pretty readable on my end just confused

Comment: @kaseyjohannssen please add the error in code blocks (as you did for your main code). I tried editing your answer but couldn't submit the edit due to too much code